# Access variables in method scope from inside anonymous class

Tags: java, variables, scope, shadowing

How can I print 12 by the value of `x = 12`  in the following code,
**Note We Can't change the variable names**

```java
public class Master {
    final static int x = 10;

    private void display() {
        final int x = 12; // How to print this in run() method

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            final int x = 15;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int x = 20;

                System.out.println(x);  //20
                System.out.println(this.x); //15
                System.out.println();// What to write here to print (x = 12)
                System.out.println(Master.x); //10
            }
        };

        r.run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Master m = new Master();
        m.display();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you shouldn't be able to. `x=12` is a variable local to your method. In theory the `master.this.x` shouldn't be visible neither, but you can access it because while executing the anonymous runnable, the outer class instance exists. FYI: you should start class names with a capital letter `Master`, otherwise you might mistake them for a variable.

Comment: I think only way to do that change the x=12 to xx=12 then use it directly in the runnable :) nice question though

Comment: recommend renaming variables/fields - so it is only good for confusing readers (and bit of learning)

Comment: Actually this is a nice question concerning variable name scopes and shadowing. In your case I think it's not possible to access the x of the method without renaming it.

Comment: P.S., I removed the "multithreading" tag because  the question appears to have nothing to do with threads.

Comment: neither does it have anything to do with "printf" :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Master {
    final int x = 10;

    private void display() {
        final int x = 12;

        class RunImpl implements Runnable {
            int xFromAbove;
            int x = 15;

            private RunImpl(int x) {
                this.xFromAbove = x;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int x = 20;
                System.out.println(x);               //20
                System.out.println(this.x);          //15
                System.out.println(this.xFromAbove); //12
                System.out.println(Master.this.x);   //10
            }
        }

        RunImpl r = new RunImpl(x);
        r.run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Master m = new Master();
        m.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case you override x = 15 in the constructor.

Comment: nice workaround, although `this.x` (15) will no longer be available

Comment: renaming the variables would have been much better

Comment: If you're going to change the code, change x = 12 to y = 12.  Then just print y.

Comment: Sorry but you can't change the variable names

Comment: @Dilwar A variable was added, nothing was renamed

Comment: yes @cricket_007 But the value is passed via Constructor. I need a direct way to print that value like other 'x's

Comment: @Dilwar There's no way to access the scope of the outer method and you've shadowed that variable, anyway, locally